# How to get a result of particular function in a JSP page using JQUERY AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

Is it possible to run a particular function on another JSP page which contains many other functions using jQuery AJAX and retrieve the result of that particular function onto the JSP page.

Comment: AJAX, You already answered the question, but note that the client can see only one view at a time. Also the function you want to run should be in the current page the user is viewing.

Comment: Why do you want run the javascript function in another jsp page? If the function is independent of the page, why don't you write a common javascript external file?

Comment: I got that but i need to update many fields in my page dynamically. So i have to write a jsp pages for each field.